# Automatically download statements from banks and utilities

Tags: pdf, automation, finance

**Background**: Going paperless is really popular and every bank and utility seems to want me to go paperless.  My main gripe about doing so is that now I have to go out and download statements from 10 different web sites instead of just waiting for the next statement to show up in the mail.  I'm all for saving trees, but it seems silly to burns hours clicking around when I could do the filing with paper in minutes.  (How many people actually download their statements?)

So, is there any free **software that will automatically download statements from companies**?
Or is there any software that could be easily adapted to do so?

## Requirements

- runs in Linux or Mac (we have no Windows around here)
- works with at least one of ADP, Chase, Citibank, Fidelity, or Verizon Wireless already
- can save the files into Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.

## Hopes

- that it will figure out how often statements show up and alert if they're late
- that it is written in Perl, Go, Rust or python.